# Python sockets are not connecting

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tkinter, python-sockets

I am building a messaging application, I can get two of the scripts to connect and communicate on the same machine, but on two separate machines on the same LAN, they do not connect at all. I have made a firewall exception on both computers for the program but it doesn't help.

The host just hangs while it listens for a connection from the client that never comes, and the client eventually times out saying there was no response or an improper response after a minute of waiting.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import tkinter as tk

default_port = 43777
self_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def client_link():
    self_socket.connect((join_ip_input.get("1.0", "end-1c"), default_port))
    create_messenging_screen()
    self_socket.sendall(("hi to you too").encode("utf-8"))
    while True:
        try:
            print(self_socket.recv(1024))
        except:pass

def host_link():
    self_socket.bind((socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), default_port))

    self_socket.listen(1)

    global client_conn
    client_conn, client_addr = self_socket.accept()
    create_messenging_screen()

    client_conn.sendall(("hi").encode("utf-8"))
    print(client_addr)

    while True:
        try:
            print(client_conn.recv(1024))
        except:pass

def continue_setup(route):
    if route == None:
        Thread(target=host_link).start()
    else:

        Thread(target=client_link).start()


def create_messenging_screen():
   #clear the window and create the messaging GUI

window = tk.Tk()
#IM app connection screen

#host a chatroom
button(window, command=lambda: continue_setup(None))
#join a chatroom
join_ip_input = tk.Text(window)
button(window, command=lambda: continue_setup(1))

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have two windows machines, I'm using the local IP address that socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname() gives me to create the socket of the host machine

Comment: Make sure the output of `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` in server side is the same as the input in client side.  Also better change `join_ip_input.get("1.0", "end-1c")` to `join_ip_input.get("1.0", "end-1c").strip('\n')` to remove unexpected trailing newlines.  I have tested your code (after fixing some typo issues, like `button` should be `tk.Button`) and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my computer had two network adaptors and the default one that the socket module was using didn't work, so i specified the other one using this: `socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())[2][1]`.